# Loading a slide depending on what day it is?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there any way to show a certain slide in flash CS5 depending on what day of the week it is? Say for example its Monday the flash file on load will show a slide designed for Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, use the Date() class to find out what date it is (according to system clock) and use the day (number 0 to 6) to find out which day of the week it is and load according to that.